# Difference between yield [] & yield all() - ES6/redux-saga

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, yield, redux-saga

Is there any advantage in using redux-saga's `yield all([])` over `ES6`'s built-in `yield []`?

To run multiple operations in parallel, redux-saga suggests:

```
const result = yield all([
  call(fetchData),
  put(FETCH_DATA_STARTED),
]);
```

But the same can be accomplished without the `all()` method:

```
const result = yield [
  call(fetchData),
  put(FETCH_DATA_STARTED),
];
```

Which one is better & why?

Comment: telling by the [documentation](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#alleffects), basically the same differrence as between `Promise.all([...])` and `Promise.resolve([...])`

Comment: They are doing the same thing - spawn tasks and wait for all of them to finish. BTW, yielding an array isn't a specific ES6 feature, it's a `redux-saga` thing.

Comment: In fact neither is built into ES6. If you are using generator functions, redux-saga is handling all the values.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no functional difference, as **Mateusz Burzyński** (redux-saga maintainer) explains [here](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1073#issuecomment-315051497):

> Under the hood they are both the same, `yield [...effects]` will result in a deprecation warning though and inform you about `all`.
>
> This was introduced to make parallel behaviour **explicit** and it nicely mirrors [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

It's preferred to use `all()` as it informs the reader that we're yielding more than 1 effect here, but the various uses of yield will still work without it:

**yielding an object with multiple effects**

```
const { company, profile } = yield {
  company: select(getCompany),
  profile: select(getUserProfile, userId),
};
```

**yielding an array literal**

```
yield [
  put(userRequestSucceeded(userId)),
  put(userReceived(response.data)),
];
```

**yielding an array using map**

```
yield userIds.map(userId => call(fetchUserDetails, userId));
```